# Margin underneath image when linked

Tags: css, image, border, margin

I've looked everywhere and can't find an answer for this, I think possibly because nobody has had the same problem, or possibly because it's a very specific problem.

The problem I'm having is, that linked images on the site I'm working on, have a small border underneath when hovered over, this is in all browsers (apart from IE 7, which the site was designed originally in). This is due to setting a:hover as having a background. Despite setting no borders, margins and padding to images, it's still not happy for some reason.

I only have 2 ways to solve it, set a class with no background on certain a tags, or display the linked image as a block. Unfortunately both these solutions aren't suitable, because the site has hundreds of pages, and possibly thousands of linked images, using a class means finding them all! Using display block will break some of the displays of images, such as the when they're centered nicely in a p tag.

If you want an example of it not working for me, the homepage of the site in question is http://www.tameside.gov.uk, look at the social media icons in the top right, they're all getting the background hover treatment.

If anyone could help I'd be really grateful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The image icons are PNG and have a transparent background. That is why you can see the background.
You can change the icons to have white background (same them as JPEG) and you will no longer see the background.

A faster fix would be to add a new CSS rule that apply only to the a tags inside the social media div:

```
.banner_container .social a {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but they're not actually transparent, they have white backgrounds, it also occurs on all jpegs. However after a lot of searching and some of my own knowledge I figured out why the problem occurs and the solution.

Comment: Hi. I am glad you fixed it. What was the solution?

Comment: Sorry meant to put the solution but clicked submit early: All images are inline by default, therefore they sit on an imaginary line inside a div or wherever they are, the line is there because of the lower items that sit below a line naturally, such as 'g' in most fonts. Because a:hover had a background, it was picking that line up as well creating a margin underneath. The solution is either to display all images as a block (which wouldn't work for me), or add vertical-align: text-bottom, which hardly changes the images alignment, but puts it down enough to overlap that imaginary line.